# Converting my application to new Swift - error "Extra argument in call"

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I recently converted my watch app to Swift 4 and I received the following error: "Extra argument 'var2' in call".
The code is in a Singleton with an array/dictionary, here is the reference code:

```
class foo {

    static let sharedInstance = foo()

    var currentFlag: Bool = true
    var a:[(var1: Int, var2:Int, var3:Bool)] = []

    private init() {
    }

    func test(v1:Int, v2:Int) {
        a.append(var1: v1, var2: v2, var3: Bool(currentFlag)) // <-- error here 
    } 
}
```

Comment: My bad, I converted to Swift 3 not 4 but the solution below fixed the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check this proposal for Swift 4:
[SE-0110 Distinguish between single-tuple and multiple-argument function types](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0110-distingish-single-tuple-arg.md)

Some implementation details have changed in betas, but in your case, you need to append another pair of parentheses:

```
func test(v1:Int, v2:Int) {
    a.append((var1: v1, var2: v2, var3: Bool(currentFlag)))
}
```

---

By the way, you declare your `currentFlag` as `Bool`, so `Bool(currentFlag)` is sort of redundant:

```
func test(v1:Int, v2:Int) {
    a.append((var1: v1, var2: v2, var3: currentFlag))
}
```